# Regular Expression for floating point or string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression that matches a floating point or a string expression.

I.e. a text to match might look like this:

```
ABC 3.101
DEF 5.0
HIJ ?Error
KLM 1.0
NOP Range
```

My current version is:

```
fp_word = r"(?:[-+]?\d+.\d+|\w+\?)"
```

but its not matching the `?Error` or `Range` case.

It should match

```
3.101
5.0
?Error (including the question mark)
1.0
Range
```

Comment: What would your desired regex reject?

Comment: Is it enough to capture everything between the space character and the end of the line?

Comment: @kpie It should return what I wrote at the end of  the question ("It should match"). Is this what you mean?

Comment: @aaossa The example is to show only that in a column can be floating points and strings. On a given row there are multiple floating points after each other separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is this:

```
(?:[-+]?\d+.\d+|\w+\?)
```

It is not matching non-numeric strings because you are trying to match 1+ word characters followed by a literal `?` i.e. `?` after the string. Whereas in your input you have just one value that starts with `?` and other one doesn't even have a `?` so both are failing to match.

If I understand your requirements correctly you can just use this regex:

```sh
[ ]([-+]?\d+.\d+|\S+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6SPqht/1)

It starts matching with a space and matched either a signed floating point number or 1+ of non-whitespace i.e. `\S+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<= ).+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ujzYPR/3). It matches any one or more chars other than line break chars till the end of a line after the first space.

If your regex should only match a number or some word optionally preceded with a `?` char and you want to use your regex, but only match at a (non)word boundary you can use

```
(?:\b(?=\w)|\B(?=\W))(?!^)(?:[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\??\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ujzYPR/2). Here,

- `(?:\b(?=\w)|\B(?=\W))` - an [adaptive dynamic word boundary of Type 2 (YouTube video explanation)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68): it matches a word boundary if the next char is a word char, else, the position must be a non-word boundary position
- `(?!^)` - not the start of string position
- `(?:[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\??\w+)` - either

  - `[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional `+` or `-` and then one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\??\w+` - an optional `?` and one or more word chars.